# Azure AD authentication and authorization in ASP.NET Framework console app

Tags: asp.net, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have been searching for a few days, and was unable to find a complete example of what is required to make an **Azure AD-authenticated endpoint** in ASP.NET framework 4.8.x (**Not core**) console app.

I saw that in Core, I need to set up authorization requirements and authorization handlers, but understood that that is not the correct startegy for ASP.NET framework. I was unable to find how to do that in regular ASP.NET.

What I expect:

1) I want to mark endpoints with the Authorize[PolicyName] attribute

2) Set some function `f` to occur whenever a call is made to the marked endpoints

3) Have `f` get the JWT received at the endpoint

4) Have `f`'s results (Say, a boolean. Although updating an authentication context is also great) determine whether the flow would continue into the function marked with the Authorize[PolicyName] attribute

So given `f`, what else would I want to do to make sure only calls approved by it proceed?